# Local Database not present in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I cannot find Local Database when I try to add new item to my project[No Local Database in the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsBLq.png)

Answer (score 2):

The Local Database item template creates a SQL Server CE SDF data file.  Microsoft is no longer developing SQL Server CE and now recommends SQLite as the default file-based data format for .NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VS2015, but in VS2013, right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and choose `Add` -> `Existing Item...` This will bring up a file selection dialog where you can find your existing files. You can also get to this dialog via `Project` -> `Add Existing Item...`

This procedure is also documented on [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179402%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), and is likely to be identical for VS2015.